# How to print a concatenation of strings in Korn Shell

Tags: ksh

This is my script

```
[root@localhost scripts]# cat nested.sh
#!/bin/ksh

echo Enter the level of nesting
read lev
echo Enter the directory \( Enter the Absolute Path\)
read path
echo Enter the directory name
read $dirname
cd $path
for((i=1;i<=$lev;i++));
 do
  mkdir '$dirname$i'
  cd '$dirname$i'
 done
echo $dirname$i
```

Assume that towards the end the value of $dirname is "fold" and value of $i is "5".
I was expecting the last statement `echo $dirname$i` to print fold5
but instead it only prints 5.

Can someone please explain how to print "fold5" ?
Also can someone please explain why it only printed 5 for me ?

Comment: It looks better to get read to show the prompt: `read dirname?"Enter the directory name: "`

Comment: Thanks @glenn jackman, will definitely start following this :)

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo on line 8 of your script, it should be:
`read dirname`
That's the reason you only get '5' printed, because $dirname is empty.

What is happening is that when you do `read $dirname` the shell expands '$dirname' to it's value which is empty.

Also on a side note, always use double-quotes when enclosing variables.

Revised script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo Enter the level of nesting
read lev
echo Enter the directory \( Enter the Absolute Path\)
read path
echo Enter the directory name
read dirname
cd $path
for((i=1;i<=$lev;i++));
 do
  mkdir "$dirname$i"
  cd "$dirname$i"
 done
echo "$dirname$i"
```

Comment: And when you call `read` with no variable, the user's data is stored in the `$REPLY` variable: to demonstrate: `read; echo "$REPLY"`

Comment: Thanks glenn jackman & Dalvenjia, silly mistake on my part